# Differences in these 3 way to instantiate an object dynamically?

Tags: php, oop, object

Out of curiosity, what's the difference (if any, e.g. performance) of creating instances in PHP using one of the following way?

```
class MyClass { }

// Direct
$name     = 'MyClass';
$instance = new $name;

// Using ReflectionClass
$reflector = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');
$instance  = $reflector->newInstance();

// Really don't know if it's going to work
$instance = call_user_func(array('MyClass', '__construct'));
```

Comment: Keep it simple - stay with the first one. Reflection will use more resources, and yeah... I'm not sure the thirf one will work either. Remember that __construct has no return clause, so called explicitly it won't return an object (I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct is "the normal way"

Using ReflectionClass is what you would do if you your program had to figure out classes etc on the fly - no need to do this in most cases. It will typically be a bit more resource hungry and slower (perhaps not noticably)

Not sure about the 3rd one - falls into the KISS principle - Since "Direct" works, I've never got into such a twisted situation as to even come up with that 3rd approach.